# Where do people take foliage trips?

Tags: idioms, american-english, phrase-usage

“Foliage trip” (meaning a trip to the forest in autumn to see the beautifully-colored leaves before they fall) is [a fairly recent US expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foliage+trip%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cfoliage+trip%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfoliage%20trip%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0), apparently having [made it into print in the 1950s](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22foliage%20trip%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:1969&lr=lang_en). A very casual web search suggests that the term is predominantly from New England, or at least from the US North-East.

Is this the case? Where do people use “foliage trip”? Outside of the US North-East (in similar climates, and in climates where the beautiful colors of fall leaves isn't a thing), do people understand the expression? Does British English have an equivalent expression ([for French the jury is still out](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21870/translation-of-foliage-trip))?

Comment: BrE probably doesn't have an equivalent because even *we* know that the best example is [Autumn in Vermont](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22autumn+in+vermont%22) (even if Americans insist on enthusing about [**Fall** in Vermont](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22autumn+in+vermont%22#safe=off&tbm=bks&q=%22fall+in+vermont%22) :)

Comment: Note also: ***Leaf peeping*** is an informal term in the United States for the activity in which people travel to view and photograph the fall foliage in areas where foliage changes colors in autumn, particularly in New England. ***The origin of the term "leaf peeping" is not well known. A similar custom in Japan is called momijigari.*** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_peeping

Comment: I've never heard of a *foliage trip* — a *fall foliage trip* is unremarkable, but always *fall foliage*; a *foliage trip* is a little precious. Most enthusiasts I know (granted, neither many nor necessarily representative) do *fall color trips*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We do have [something to offer in the genre](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=autumn+pictures+in+england&num=50&tbm=isch&imgil=yOswZwggzOo9RM%253A%253BEjFmQK7Xcy6oiM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.telegraph.co.uk%25252Fgardening%25252Fgardeningpicturegalleries%25252F9651657%25252FAutumn-colour-in-England-this-orange-and-pleasant-land.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=yOswZwggzOo9RM%253A%252CEjFmQK7Xcy6oiM%252C_&usg=__f8mM7FdmrZ59A2ktL-mpS-UrHt4%3D&biw=1366&bih=588&ved=0ahUKEwiEhsvi8oDPAhUmL8AKHUhWCMsQyjcIKQ&ei=hfDRV8SvJabegAbIrKHYDA#imgrc=osOFApMuhn0zkM%3A)

Comment: Like @choster, I've never heard "foliage trip" (I'm from upstate New York). People do regularly talk about seeing "the (fall) colors" and "the leaves", though.

Comment: It's probably more idiomatic with "tour/s" than with "trip/s" but in spite of not getting many hits, I kind of like either "Fall Foliage Fling" or "Fall Foliage Folly."

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought it was [*Moonlight in Vermont*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_in_Vermont_(song))?

Comment: The concept is reasonably well understood (as is the term, though more as "foliage tour") in the US "Upper Midwest" -- Minnesota, Wisconsin, Michigan.

Comment: Althought I suspect *leaf peeper tour* will be the normal 3rd person reference for this for the foreseeable future, it's mildly depricating and not a term the Chamber of Commerce is going to use to attract visitors to the area. So some clever tourist board writer must have invented a new one. The [fall foliage forecast](https://www.romanticasheville.com/fall.htm) has been a staple product of tourist boards and travel agencies for a long time.

Comment: People from the *mid*-Midwest call it *fall chasing*. But you pretty much have to travel the "Upper" to do it, or the East Coast.

Comment: two itineraries: http://www.amtrakvacations.com/vacation/new-england-fall-foliage/ 
https://www.amtrak.com/fall-travel-on-the-great-dome-car

Comment: The colours of foliage depend on species and local weather conditions.  The colours of the Northern American forests are mainly due to the *Quercus rubra* species (known as the "northern red oak")  native of North America and although in the last couple of centuries it has been tried to grow it in some parts of Europe (Périgord and Alsace in France), not long enough and not on a large enough scale to achieve the spectacular colours of the large ancestral forests of *Quercus rubra* in Northern America. Fall foliage trips are a typical Am. activity,  as visiting medieval castles is in Europe.

Comment: @WS2 I see your search results and raise you mine! ;-) https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=autumn+bracken&espv=2&biw=847&bih=690&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHrojJ-4HPAhVaFMAKHTtXAscQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=autumn+scotland not that I'm being competitive...

Comment: I grew up in Rhode Island, went to college in upstate New York, and then lived in Boston~ I have never heard anyone say the words "foliage trip." I think we just call it "going outside."

Comment: Which isn't to say nobody says it, but rather that it's sufficiently rare that I didn't encounter it in 20+ years living there.

Answer (score 5):

The term that Wikipedia is familiar with is [leaf peeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_peeping) (origin unknown). It seems to be more popular than "foliage trip", which seems to be exclusively used for New England tourism (I can't find any British usage).

The phrase *leaf peeping* is used in some UK sources, but it's likely to be unfamiliar to many people.

[The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/picturegalleries/8034331/Places-for-leaf-peeping-four-of-the-best.html) says it well:

> It may sound like something unsavoury types get up to in parks, but leaf peeping is in fact the popular American pursuit of admiring the dramatic changing autumn foliage colours.

The term is not even well-known in many areas in the US, much less the UK.

Comment: Nothing to do with fig leaves?

Answer (score 3):

The term 'foliage trip' appears in a Vermont newspaper in 1909. As reproduced in the *Chronicling America* corpus of US newspapers, it is there modified by 'autumn':

> They were celebrating their seventh wedding anniversary in taking an *autumn foliage trip* through the Berkshires, the Green mountains and the Connecticut valley....

([*The Bennington Evening Banner*](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn95066012/1909-10-15/ed-1/seq-7/#date1=1789&index=0&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=foliage+trip&proxdistance=5&date2=1922&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=foliage+trip&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), October 15, 1909. Emphasis mine.)

The term reappears without a modifying 'fall' or 'autumn' in 1931, in [*The True Republican*](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=STR19311021.2.33&txq=%22foliage%20trip%22#), Sycamore, Illinois. Here the context and the date of the publication make 'fall' or 'autumn' superfluous:

[image: foliagetrip]

In 1964, an appearance in *Lancaster Farming* (Pennsylvania) is modified by 'autumn'. Subsequent appearances in 1971 and 1973 are found in newspapers from Missouri and Illinois, where the term is modified by 'fall'. In 1975 and 1981, the term appears in Texas newspapers, unmodified. In 1983, 1985 and 1995, the term appears in three more Texas newspapers, modified by 'fall'.

All the above appearances can be viewed in context by following links from the two pages of an [*Elephind* search for 'foliage trip'](http://www.elephind.com/?a=q&results=1&r=1&e=-------en-10--11-byDA-txt-txINtxCO-%22foliage%20trip%22---------).

Beyond uses (including more recent ones than are shown in the *Elephind* search) in the Northeast, Mid-Atlantic, Southeast and Midwest states of the US, a search of the *NOW Corpus* reveals an appearance in Toronto.

The more common variant, 'foliage tour', likewise occurs in newspapers (digital and otherwise) published in the eastern and midwestern regions of the US, as well as southeastern Canada (as evidenced by appearances in *Toronto Star*). This variant first appears in the *Elephind* corpus in 1916, in the "Travel" section of the *Richmond Times-Dispatch* (Virginia), where it is used in the title of an pseudo-news advertisement describing two tours: "Summer Vacation Tour and Autumn Foliage Tour of JAPAN". Four later appearances in 1917, in newspapers from Pennsylvania and New York, are also modified by 'fall'.

After 1917, the 'foliage tour' variant does not crop up again in the *Elephind* corpus until 1956, in the *Lancaster Farming* newspaper from Pennsylvania where 'foliage trip' turns up in 1964. Subsequently, approximately 200 (discounting duplicates) instances of ['foliage tour' appear in the *Elephind* corpus](http://www.elephind.com/?a=q&hs=1&r=1&results=1&txq=%22foliage%20tour%22&txf=txINtxCO&o=10&dafyq=&dafmq=&dafdq=&datyq=&datmq=&datdq=&puqname=Search%20all%20titles...&puq=&lcq=&csq=&e=-------en-10--1-byDA-txt-txINtxCO-%22foliage%20trip%22---------).

---

About your questions:

> Where do people use “foliage trip”?

As detailed above, to the best of my external-evidence-based knowledge. Having grown up in the midwestern US, I can attest from personal experience that the terms 'foliage trip' and 'foliage tour' were common there from the 1960s through the 1990s at least. I have no doubt they still are, but can't attest to it from personal experience.

> Outside of the US North-East (in similar climates, and in climates where the beautiful colors of fall leaves isn't a thing), do people understand the expression?

Yes. There's nothing mysterious about the expression, and many English-speaking people will be acquainted with the beauty of autumn foliage colors, if not from direct experience then from photographs and films.

> Does British English have an equivalent expression...?

Not to my knowledge, although, for the reasons mentioned with respect to general understanding of the term in English, British people probably wouldn't find either expression mystifying, particularly as modified by 'fall' or 'autumn'. They might be inclined to sneer at the expression on the grounds that it's an American expression, but that's par for the course.